# Looking up data within a file versus merging

Tags: stata

I have a file that look at ratings that teacher `X` gives to teacher `Y` and the date it occurs

```
clear 
rating_id   RatingTeacher   RatedTeacher  Rating          Date     
  1              15             12          1          "1/1/2010"
  2              12             11          2          "1/2/2010"
  3              14             11          3          "1/2/2010"
  4              14             13          2          "1/5/2010"
  5              19             11          4          "1/6/2010"
  5              11             13          1          "1/7/2010"
 end
```

I want to look in the history to see how many times the `RatingTeacher` had been rated at the time they make the rating and the cumulative score. The result would look like this.

```
rating_id   RatingTeacher   RatedTeacher  Rating          Date      TimesRated    CumulativeRating  
  1              15             12          1          "1/1/2010"       0              0
  2              12             11          2          "1/2/2010"       1              1
  3              14             11          3          "1/2/2010"       0              0
  4              14             13          2          "1/5/2010"       0              0
  5              19             11          4          "1/6/2010"       0              0
  5              11             13          1          "1/7/2010"       3              9
 end
```

I have been merging the dataset with itself to get this to work, and it is fine. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this within the file

Comment: Please study http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @NickCox Added thank you for pointing this out

Comment: It is helpful to provide code that generates the data. This way people can tinker (and provide code that you can cut-and-paste into your own code :) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your input data, I guess that the last `rating_id` should be 6 and that dates are MDY. Statalist members are asked to use `dataex` (SSC) to set up data examples. This isn't Statalist but there is no reason for lower standards to apply. See [the Statalist FAQ](http://www.statalist.org/forums/help#stata)

I rarely see even programmers be precise about what they mean by "efficient", whether it means fewer lines of code, less use of memory, more speed, something else or is just some all-purpose term of praise.  This code loops over observations, which can certainly be slow for large datasets. More [in this paper](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0033)

We can't compare with your `merge` solution because you don't give the code.

```
clear 
input rating_id RatingTeacher RatedTeacher Rating str8 SDate 
1 15 12 1 "1/1/2010"
2 12 11 2 "1/2/2010"
3 14 11 3 "1/2/2010"
4 14 13 2 "1/5/2010"
5 19 11 4 "1/6/2010"
6 11 13 1 "1/7/2010"
end 
gen Date = daily(SDate, "MDY") 
sort Date 

gen Wanted = . 
quietly forval i = 1/`=_N' { 
    count if Date <  Date[`i'] & RatedT == RatingT[`i'] 
    replace Wanted = r(N) in `i' 
} 

list, sep(0)  

     +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | rating~d   Rating~r   RatedT~r   Rating      SDate    Date   Wanted |
     |---------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |        1         15         12        1   1/1/2010   18263        0 |
  2. |        2         12         11        2   1/2/2010   18264        1 |
  3. |        3         14         11        3   1/2/2010   18264        0 |
  4. |        4         14         13        2   1/5/2010   18267        0 |
  5. |        5         19         11        4   1/6/2010   18268        0 |
  6. |        6         11         13        1   1/7/2010   18269        3 |
     +---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Out of curiosity if I wanted to limit to searching in the last 2 days from the record in question why doesn't modifying the code with `count if Date <  Date[`i']-2 & RatedT == RatingT[`i'] ` not work?

Comment: Works fine for me. The values of the last variable run `0 0 0 0 0 2` which seems to check out.

Comment: but it should be `0 0 0 0 0 1`

Comment: Two previous evaluations, in observations 2 and 3.

Comment: My code was wrong. Should be & `(Date[`i'`] - Date <= 2)`

Comment: I see. I interpreted your code, not your wording. Either way, the method can be extended.

Answer (score 0):

The building block is that the rater and ratee are a pair. You can use `egen`'s `group()` to give a unique ID to each rater ratee pair.

```
egen pair = group(rater ratee)
bysort pair (date): timesRated = _n
```

Comment: I think this assumes more structure than the data possess. From the example, teachers can be rated by one or more colleagues; they aren't paired off.

Comment: @NickCox Oh, you're right! If he wants number of time each teacher is rated, then it's just `bysort ratee (date) : generate timesRated = _n`, right?

Comment: That says nothing about being rated before they rate.

Comment: @RichardHerron NickCox has the right interpretation. It is about how many times a teacher has been rated by any colleague before the focal rating